# Pandas rolling average on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I wonder whether the behaviour of applying `rolling` on a `groupby` object with a `MuliIndex` described below is expected. The issue is that using `rolling` directly on `groupby` does not retain the `MultiIndex`. However, using `apply` on `groupby` keeps the index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1, 1, 2, 2], ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue']], names=['number', 'color']))
```

I want to calculate the rolling average per group in `level='number'`. Applying `rolling` directly on `groupby`, the result is indexed by the single `level='number'`, dropping `level='color'`:

```
df.groupby(level='number').rolling(window=2).mean()


          0
number     
1       NaN
1       1.5
2       NaN
2       3.5
```

I can obtain the desired result using `apply` on `groupby`

```
df.groupby(level='number').apply(lambda x: x.rolling(2).mean())

                0
number color     
1      red    NaN
       blue   1.5
2      red    NaN
       blue   3.5
```

Is the behaviour of `groupby().rolling()` on the `MultiIndex` a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is a bug and will be fixed in pandas version 1.2.3, see [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/38523) reported in the pandas repository on GitHub.